# Install linux on mac

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mac, multi-boot, operating-systems

Can I install linux system like ubuntu in mac book. I'm planning to buy a mac, and I don not want to give up the linux.

And if so, is there important flaw to install linux as os in mac, or try to multi-system?

Comment: Have you tried to google this question before asking?

Comment: You can readily run Linux (any variant) inside VMware Fusion as a virtual machine. There are other virtualization apps for MAC as well.  I do this in Windows.

Comment: Why are you buying a Mac if you don't want to give up Linux? It's just an expensive laptop in that case. Also, macOS has BSD underneath so you can still use the command line tools if that's what you want.

Comment: I just want to try new thing since the IOS give me a good experience. Not just the command line, I like full linux ecology and feature.

Answer (score 0):

Most Macs/MacBooks are based on x86_64, so you should be able to boot into a Linux installation drive simply by holding down the Option key at boot. I was actually able to install Windows 10 on my Macbook Pro without Bootcamp! And I have tried booting into several Linux distros on my Mac without any problem. There is no important flaw to be worried about.

Comment: Thanks for the infomation